# How to set HDFS as statebackend for flink

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to store flink store in HDFS so that after crash I can recover the flink state from HDFS. I am planning to write state to HDFS every 60 second. How Can I achieve this ?
Is this the config I need to follow ?
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/ops/state/state_backends.html#setting-default-state-backend

And where do I specify the check point interval ? Any link or sample code would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choosing where checkpoints are stored (e.g., HDFS) is separate from deciding which state backend to use for managing your working state (which can be on-heap, or in local files managed by the RocksDB library).

These two concepts were cleanly separated in Flink 1.12. In early versions of Flink, the two appeared to be more strongly related than they actually are because the filesystem and rocksdb state backend constructors took a file URI as a parameter, specifying where the checkpoints should be stored.

The best way to manage all of this is to leave this out of your code, and to specify the configuration you want in `flink-conf.yaml`, e.g.,

```yaml
state.backend: filesystem
state.checkpoints.dir: hdfs://namenode-host:port/flink-checkpoints
execution.checkpointing.interval: 10s
```

Comment: Thanks David At this moment, I am running flink on my local laptop. Where will flink-state be stored if I have configuration like this 

```state.backend: rocksdb
state.checkpoints.dir: file:///data/flink/checkpoints
```

Comment: Flink state is always stored in two places. In this particular case the location of the working state is determined by `state.backend.rocksdb.localdir` (which will be /tmp if not otherwise set), and the checkpoints will be stored where you have configured them.

Comment: I am confused by statement that "working state is determined by state.backend.rocksdb.localdir" . So state.checkpoints.dir determines where the checkpoints are stored ? what determines where the state is stored ?
I like to understand the diff where the state and check points are stored for

```state.backend: filesystem
   state.checkpoints.dir: hdfs://namenode-host:port/flink-checkpoints
   execution.checkpointing.interval: 10s
```
and 
```state.backend: rocksdb
   state.checkpoints.dir: file:///data/flink/checkpoints
```

Comment: If you use the heap-based state backend, the working state is stored in memory, on the JVM heap. With rocksdb, the working state is on the local disk, typically in /tmp, but it's wherever `state.backend.rocksdb.localdir` puts it -- plus rocksdb will also use an off-heap block cache. Then the checkpoints are stored according to `state.checkpoints.dir`, which in production should always point to a distributed file system (since the heap and local disk are easily lost in the event of a failure).

Comment: Checkpoints are only used to restore the working state during restarts. It's the working state that is actually used by your application, and the working state is always local.

Answer (score 1):

Information about checkpointing and savepointing can be found at https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/checkpointing/

On how to configure HDFS as a filesystem, you should check https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/filesystems/overview/